# How to configure wild card or custom domains in redirect uri in google OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, custom-domain

I'm using Google API for integrating google drive for upload/download/get/create files and folder functionalities with C# Web API 2.0.
I want to configure wild card or custom domains in redirect uri as my application support custom domain for each and every customer. Each time when customer register with my application they can generate their own custom domain for example:-

Customer 1 Application URL: https://abc-myapplication.com
Customer 2 Application URL: https://xyz-myapplication.com

How can I dynamically add redirect uri or can I add wild card redirect uri like **https://*-myapplication.com**?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aG4j.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with arbitrary amount of redirect URIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456821/how-to-deal-with-arbitrary-amount-of-redirect-uris)