# Google API Multilpe domain with Single API Key and OAuth 2.0 client IDs

Tags: php, google-drive-api, filepicker

I am using “Google Picker API” for my website which contains the domain and multiple subdomains (Main domain: www.example.com and Subdomain: *.example.com). I have created API Key and OAuth 2.0 client IDs but it’s working only for the Main domain. Is there any way/setting to work the same API Key and OAuth 2.0 client IDs for Main domain and Subdomain.

Thanks

Comment: Subdomain wildcard is not supported by OAuth. According to vlatko "Wildcard matching subdomains is not supported in Google OAuth. You could try using the state parameter and include the user-specific information there. This parameter will be returned to you in the response." Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652062/subdomain-in-google-console-redirect-uris) for more information about his answer and workaround.

Comment: thanks Mr. Rebot, but there is any other chance to do this by writing custom code or using CURL.