# How to set origin manually when use web google auth

Tags: javascript

We are developing enterprise application which means we provide FE instance per customer:

https://customer1.example.com
https://customer2.example.com,
...

We'd like to use one client_id for all of them. But we are getting origin issue.

We can't add hunderds or thousands origins cause of number of origins restriction.
So we are going to set origin manually when we do auth. But there is no documentation how to set  the origin when do web google auth.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know this solution but divide into different client_id according to user ID value range

Comment: this solution may help for you 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19337454/13647574